# Can I assign an operator to a variable?

Tags: r

In R, is it possible to assign an operator to a variable or some other construct that allows the variable to be used as an operator?  In my case, I want some code to use either the %do% or %dopar% operator from the foreach package (depending on whether the user wants parallel computation or not).  The block of code to execute remains the same, its just the operator that's variable.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by whats problem with eval function ?! you can just pass desirable command as string to eval !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called operator overloading, and here is a simple example:

```
"%do%" <- function(a, b){
  if(do_plus){
    a + b
  } else {
    a - b
  }
}

do_plus <- TRUE

3 %do% 4
[1] 7

do_plus <- FALSE

3 %do% 4
[1] -1
```

Answer (score 5):

You're asking the wrong question.  Just use `%dopar%` and call `registerDoSEQ` if you're not running in parallel.  With `%dopar%`, the code doesn't change, just the backend does.